# Regex - don't match if pattern begins with \

Tags: regex

```
(?:[^\\])\*(.*?)\*
```

This works, however it doesn't match if the string begins with *something* so I need to somehow make it match nothing at the beginning or anything but \

Edit with examples:

```
"text *something*" - matches (correct)
"text \*something*" - doesnt match (correct)
"*something* text" - doesnt match (incorrect)
```

Comment: Can you add some example matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:^|[^\\])\*(.*?)\*
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE4hS7/1)

- `(?:^|[^\\])` will match start of input OR anything but `\`

Answer (score 1):

If your regex flavour supports it, you can use a negative look behind:

```
(?<!\\)\*(.*?)\*
```